# How to deserialize an object with just an ID or the object itself?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, deserialization

So a very basic example of what I'm trying to do: I have a Parent class and a Child class. When deserializing the object, I want to have the option on how to deserialize it, either passing in the primitive long value or the actual object itself. Is there a way to do this? Right now, passing the child object as a long value works. However, I can't pass it in as an object. When I do so, it gives me an error saying that it can not deserialize instance of long out of START_OBJECT token.

Checked the error out and a lot of the answers seems to suggest that there's an issue with the object itself. Or implementing custom serialization (which seems overly complicated to me at the moment).

[Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389723/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-lang-string-out-of-start-object-token)

[JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202876/jsonmappingexception-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-lang-string-out-of-st)

However, when I comment out the setChild function that takes in a long value, it works fine. So it got me wondering if it's even possible to deserialize the object in multiple ways. Some additional information just in case it's helpful: I'm using the Jackson library and I'm passing the object through REST.

```
public class Parent {
    private long parentId;
    private Child childObj;

    public void setChild(Child childObj) {
        this.childObj = childObj;
    }

    public void setChild(long childId) {
        this.childObj = getChildObj(childId);
    }
}

public class Child {
    private long childId;
}
```

Just a note: if I'm just passing the Child object itself (without the Parent object), passing the entire object is fine.

Comment: Please show the JSON strings which work and don't work, and the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: I was only using an example so I don't have the actual JSON string. It works when the setter for the ID is removed so it's not the JSON string that's causing the error. And this is what I get from the ajax call. 
"Can not deserialize instance of long out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@50870a5b; line: 1, column: 1765] (through reference chain: ..."

Comment: Can you create an example which illustrates the problem and show us the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator` annotation in `Child` class:

```
class Child {

    private long childId;

    @JsonCreator
    public Child() {
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Child(long childId) {
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    //getters, setters
}
```

`Child()` will be used in case of `JSON Object` and `Child(long childId)` constructor will be used in case of `NUMBER` in `JSON`.

Comment: I tried it and got the same error. I think what's happening is that the program is somehow getting confused when deserializing the object, and for some reason, using the wrong setter function. Which would explain why using @JsonCreator doesn't work. Because it's still trying to use the setter that takes in a long instead of an object.

Comment: @Karen, you should not use setter method with `long` parameter. Try to remove it and test deserialisation process only with annotated constructors.

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't use a setter method with a long parameter? If I remove it, then passing in an object will work. I won't be able to pass in a long though.

Comment: @Karen, try to ignore this extra setter with `@JsonIgnore` annotation. You could use it in your code and it will not break a deserialisation process.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. Actually, my question ended up being answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538990/deserializing-to-object-with-overloaded-setter-with-fasterxml-jackson